# Consulta banco, classe principal retorna zero

Tags: java, classes, resultset

Estou fazendo uma consulta pegando somente um campo e um so linha e setando em uma variavel da classe principal, a questao é que dentro do try abaixo, a variavel mostra o resulta da consulta corretamente

```
  String sql1 = "select ca_id from cadastro where ca_nome = '" + nome + "';";

    try {

        PreparedStatement stmt1 = connection.prepareStatement(sql1);

        ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {

            Doacao doacao = new Doacao();
            int numero = rs.getInt(1);

            doacao.setChaveFk(numero);

        }

        stmt1.execute();
        stmt1.close();
```

e quando chamo a funcao a baixo o valor da variavel é o numero zero, esse valor é para salvar como chave estrangeira em outra tabela, alguem pode me explicar pq, que retorna zero e nao o numero consultado?

```
    Doacao doacao = new Doacao();

    String sql2 = "INSERT INTO doacao (doa_tipoDoador,"
            + "doa_ultComparecimento,"
            + "doa_tipoDoacao,"
            + "doa_hospital,"
            + "doa_paciente,"
            + "doa_situacao,"
            + "doa_dataDoacao,"
            + "fk_cad_doa"
            + ")VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {




        PreparedStatement stmt2 = connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
        stmt2.setString(1, doa.getTipoDoador());
        stmt2.setString(2, doa.getUltComparecimento());
        stmt2.setString(3, doa.getTipoDoacao());
        stmt2.setString(4, doa.getHospital());
        stmt2.setString(5, doa.getPaciente());
        stmt2.setString(6, doa.getSituacao());
        stmt2.setString(7, doa.getDataDoacao());
        stmt2.setInt(8, doa.getChaveFk());
        stmt2.execute();
        stmt2.close();
```

Obs: os dois metodos estao na mesma classe DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o primeiro objeto **doacao**, o escopo dele é dentro do while, o segundo é dentro de um outro método, ou seja, a linha `doacao.setChaveFk(numero);` seta o número apenas para o objeto dentro do while e não para o objeto que está dentro do outro método.
Na verdade, não entendi como os demais parâmetros da query do segundo método estão populados, uma vez que foi criada uma nova instância de Doacao.

Entendeu?

Se não der certo, poste o código dos dois métodos inteiros, por favor.. Fica mais fácil de entender!

Comment: entao deixa eu explicar melhor, o meu sistema salva 3 tabelas ao mesmo tempo, essa variavel "chaveFK", é chave estrangeira, usando esse select eu busco somente o numero da id da primeira tabela pra salvar nas outras 2, eu pensei q se fizesse um "setChaveFk" o valor do select ficaria armazenado na variavel da classe principal, pra quando salvar as outras duas tabelas eu pegar de la, entendeu?

Comment: so q dentro do while a classe principal retorna o valor correto, se no BD o valor for 30 retorna 30, mas um insert dentro do while nao funciona, fora do while um insert funciona mas a classe principal retorna o numero 0 da e da erro de BD.

Comment: Entendi. Acredito que se você colocar o atributo chaveFk como static dê certo o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Outra coisa.. Não entendi da onde vem o objeto **doa**. Onde é feita a instanciação dele?

Comment: é porque nao postei o inicio da funcao por causa da quantidade de caracteres     seria assim     public void adicionaDoacao(Doacao doa)   estou passando atraves de construct do jform.

Comment: Deu certo coloquei como static a variavel chaveFk e funcionou como eu queria, e pensando agora parece ate obvio colocar como static, muito obrigado valeu mesmo, ja tava ficando louco ja tentei tantas coisas.

Comment: Legal! Fico feliz por ter ajudado! Pode marcar minha resposta como "melhor resposta" e encerrar o tópico, por favor?